# Why is a network share only accessible via IP address?

Tags: windows-7, security, smb

PCH is the Popcorn Hour A-110 SMB share. I am in a domain and I am running a DNS server. I am using a M1n1wall running Pfsense with DNS forwarding to the domain server. DNS resolution does not seem to be the issue. Can someone explain the following behavior?

```
C:\Users\myself>ping pch

Pinging PCH.mydomain.com [10.10.1.108] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.10.1.108: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.10.1.108: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.10.1.108: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.10.1.108: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 10.10.1.108:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Users\myself>net view \\pch
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.

C:\Users\myself>net view \\10.10.1.108
Shared resources at \\10.10.1.108

SMP8634 Share

Share name  Type  Used as  Comment

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
share       Disk
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: I've seen this before as a result of DNS and the default domain but I don't recall how I fixed it. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the `netbios name` for your server is not the same as your domain name. It may think it's named something weird like `PCH-000AF261BD` so connections intended for `pch` are getting rejected.

Answer (score 1):

While working with samba integrated with Active Directory I`ve came across the same problem. 
The problem was in time diffrence between AD and linux server with samba. Try to sync time to AD server on client. It should help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test this right now, but is 'pch' the machine's netbios name? I don't think samba goes by regular DNS lookups.

I see you're using Windows, at least in Windows 7 you can go either to My Computer and click the network icon to the left or go to control panel -> network something (my Windows isn't in English). On the top there you have something like YOUR COMPUTER ----- SEVERAL NETWORKS ----- INTERNET. Click on the middle one (several networks), your computer will search for all netbios names it comes across on your network. If you find your machine there, use that name (and then you can see if you can change it in the machine's settings to whatever you like).

Comment: PCH is listed in the Windows Network neighborhood, but when I click on it the Exlorer times out. I can access the share only Via IP address. I only used the NET commandline because it is easier to share in a question. I will have to look at the PCH's network setting for the netbios name.

Answer (score 0):

Thd drive mapping is cached after being previously mapped using another user's credentials while logged in as the regular user.  Delete it.

Start, Control Panel, Network and Internet, Network and Sharing Center.